# drupal add to inquiry cart

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-7

I am trying to create product catalog website in which I need to include a functionality similar to add  to cart.

any visitor can add the products to inquiry cart and at the end instead of checkout he can submit the order for all the products which he have already collected in the inquiry cart.

Answer (score 0):

See the ubercart module - http://drupal.org/project/ubercart

Comment: Can we use ubercart  for non e-commerce websites

Comment: Sure. You can make it do anything you want. Use the built in cart module and write your own module to do something other than checkout with it :)